# pagination for div elements in javascript

Tags: html, pagination

I'm trying to make pagination for div html elements using javascript. But I'm having some trouble making div elements hide/show on clicking the pagination buttons which i made using bootstrap. Below is my code. HTML code for div elements:

```
<div  id="page2" >
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div><!--end div 1-->
<div  id="page3" >
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div><!--end div 2-->
<div  id="page4" >
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div><!--end div 3-->
<div id="page5" >
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div><!--end div 4-->
```

Pagination code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="text-center">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">

         <li><a href="" onclick="showPages('1')">1</a></li>
         <li><a href="" onclick="showPages('2')">2</a></li>
         <li><a href="" onclick="showPages('3')">3</a></li>
         <li><a href="" onclick="showPages('4')">4</a></li>
         <li><a href="" onclick="showPages('5')">5</a></li>

      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showPages(id){


    var totalNumberOfPages = 5;
    for(var i=1; i<=totalNumberOfPages; i++){

        if (document.getElementById('page'+i)) {

            document.getElementById('page'+i).style.display='none';
        }

    }
        if (document.getElementById('page'+id)) {

            document.getElementById('page'+id).style.display='block';
        }
};
```

What is wrong in my code??

Comment: Like @Dave94 answered, a blank `href` makes the browsers to navigate to the same URl(refreshing the page), instead a hash is used when navigating inside the page itself.

Comment: Tnk yuh:) i was checking the javascript for an hour thinking that error might be in it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsf53kh2/)

I've modified this line:

```
<a href="" onclick="showPages('2')">2</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showPages('2')">2</a>
```